# javascript change image recursively

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change an image recursively with delay on my site using javascript recursive function. Here is my js code:

```js
    const ns = 0;
    carousel(ns);
    
    function carousel(n) {
        if(n < 0 || n > 3){
            n = 0;
        }
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cooperation-ovalImg");
        x[0].src = "Images/cooperation/Oval_1.1.png";
        x[1].src = "Images/cooperation/Oval_2.1.png";
        x[2].src = "Images/cooperation/Oval_3.1.png";
        n++;
        if (n > x.length) {n = 1}
        x[n-1].src = "Images/cooperation/Oval_"+n+".png";
        setTimeout(carousel(n), 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
```

```html
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test-header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about-us.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/our-projects.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cooperation.css">
        <title>Pecode Software | IT company</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </head >


    <div class="row row-14">
                    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2">
                        <img class="cooperation-ovalImg cooperation-ovalImg-1 cooperation-oval-1" src="Images/cooperation/Oval_1.1.png" alt="">
                        <img class="cooperation_line" src="Images/cooperation/Lin.svg" alt="">
                        <img class= "cooperation-ovalImg cooperation-oval-2" src="Images/cooperation/Oval_2.1.png" alt="">
                        <img class="cooperation_line" src="Images/cooperation/Lin.svg" alt="">
                        <img class= "cooperation-ovalImg cooperation-oval-3" src="Images/cooperation/Oval_3.1.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I take the **n** parameter as i want in the future to change the image by click in addition to auto change.

But there is a problem: the environment tells me:

> Function 'carousel' runs recursively infinite, and can only end by throwing an exception

When I run the page, the script is not working; the 1st image of 3 is displayed, and is dot changing.

Comment: Please add you full code including HTML

Comment: You don't have an exit condition so it will run until it crashes. I think you should checkout the setInterval method since you want to do something in an interval.

Comment: change setTimeout(carousel(n), 5000) to setTimeout(carousel, 5000, n).

Comment: If you already use bootstrap why not using their [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel)?

Comment: you are unconditionally invoking the same function forever without ever early returning if `n` has already being used so I guess what you actually need to do is to write this instead `setTimeout(carousel, 5000, n);` so that the timer will invoke the function with that `n` value in 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, change setTimeout(carousel, 5000, n); and worked. Thanks!!

Comment: post as answer and I will aprove)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) rather than a timeout. Your environment is telling you, there is no way of exiting that function. Which is bad practise.

You should use something like this instead:

```
var myinterval;

myinterval = setInterval(function(){
    // myFunction(params)
}, 5000);

function myFunction(params){
    // Your stuff in here
}

// To exit or finish your stuff you will call
/* clearInterval(myinterval); */
```

Comment: @boandriy no problem. Use whatever suits your needs :)

Comment: @ Abdul Sadik Yalcin, sorry, your implementation looks much cleaner)

Comment: Thnaks, and sory for wasted time)

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var elements = $(".cooperation-ovalImg");

var photos = [
  'https://www.countryflags.io/be/flat/64.png',
  'https://www.countryflags.io/lk/flat/64.png',
  'https://www.countryflags.io/us/flat/64.png',
  'https://www.countryflags.io/in/flat/64.png',
  'https://www.countryflags.io/jp/flat/64.png',
  'https://www.countryflags.io/aq/flat/64.png',
  ];
  
var i = 0;

window.setInterval(function(){
 var index = i%photos.length;
 i++;
 // Looping over every element
 elements.each(function(j){
    // Now j is the index of the loop
   // Decreesing if value is higher than photos
   if(index+j>photos.length-1) index = 0-j;
   // Setting src
   $(this).attr('src',photos[index+j]);
 })
},2000)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="cooperation-ovalImg">
<img class="cooperation-ovalImg">
<img class="cooperation-ovalImg">
```

This is a example carousal

Answer (score 1):

try this one please... you have to remove timeout func from carousel func and paste it to at the beginning of code... like below...

```
const ns = 45;
setTimeout(carousel(ns), 5000);


function carousel(n) {
    if(n < 0 || n > 3){
        n = 0;
    }
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cooperation-ovalImg");
    x[0].src = "Images/cooperation/Oval_1.1.png";
    x[1].src = "Images/cooperation/Oval_2.1.png";
    x[2].src = "Images/cooperation/Oval_3.1.png";
    n++;
    if (n > x.length) {n = 1}
    x[n-1].src = "Images/cooperation/Oval_"+n+".png";
     // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```